# How do the damage mission modifiers work?

Tags: destiny

So in Destiny there are three [mission modifiers](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Mission_Modifier) which increase the amount of damage that type deals.

For example,

> Void Damage from any source is greatly increased.

How does this work in game specifically? Does this affect both enemies and allies? Will you deal and receive more damage from this type?

I assume that it's worth taking weapons with a matching damage type into the mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this essentially adds a damager modifier of 3x (sorry I couldn't find a Bungie source to quote for that number) for both damage given and received.

This [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2hypnc/elemental_damage_nightfall_burn_damage/) contains some experimental numbers are sums things up quite nicely:

> Now this makes a lot of sense. It seems that Bungie applies the 300%
>   modifier FIRST and then the elemental shield reduces that number by
>   200% due to the non-corresponding elemental damage. This would make
>   the modifier 150% for the burn element to the non-corresponding shield
>   element.
>
> In conclusion, it would be smart to assess the weekly nightfall to see
>   what shield types there are, then select weapons accordingly to take
>   down enemies the fastest. For example, if most of the enemies have
>   void shield, yet the burn element is arc, take a void weapon to take
>   down the shields then use the burn element to finish them off. This is
>   smartest in a scenario where you're taking down an ultra or heavy mob.

So even with weapons matched to the appropriate burn modifier it may still be better to have a variety of damage types especially if running a mission where there are a mixture of enemies with different shields.  For example when running hive missions wizards have solar shields but knights have arc shields so having both solar and arc damage can be helpful.

Of course you can just take the appropriate matching damage type and hope you find lots of ammo for your weapons.  This is where weapons with regenerative ammo/extra ammo pickup perks can be exceptionally useful if they match the burn modifier e.g. [Invective](http://db.destinytracker.com/inventory/item/1389842216) or [Ice Breaker](http://db.destinytracker.com/inventory/item/3118679308) for solar damage to name a couple of examples.

Comment: The closest to the source info I've seen is on [Bungie forum](http://www.bungie.net/en/Forum/Post/75569592/0/0). Still not official though.

Comment: This seems to say that you still do more damage (150%) even on the "wrong" shield type. So why does it then conclude that you should take down their shields with another weapon. As I read it shooting your void  gun at a void shield will do 100% damage and your arcburn gun will do 150% damage so this seems like a better choice... Or am I misreading somewhere?

Comment: @Chris I think because correctly matched elemental damage bonus is higher than the burn damage modifier (after taking into effect the unmatched shield damage reduction).  I've seen the standard matched elemental damage bonus (which applies by default) quoted as 2x (i.e. 200%) but again no hard references on that so that would seem to be the case.

Comment: @RobV: Ah, so there is a penalty for the wrong type and a bonus for the right type? I assumed it would just be standard for one or other and since they were talking about a penalty for the wrong I assumed right would be the norm.

Comment: Yes pretty much, when you shoot an enemy with the wrong damage type it will typically flash up as `Resist` which indicates there is a damage penalty, when you shoot an enemy with the correct damage type the damage numbers should show up in the relevant colour (purple, orange or blue) to indicate bonus damage has been dealt